# Custom Regions in PowerBI Map?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have a dataset that has Regions ("Southwest", "Northeast", "Pacific Northwest", and one "Canada" region for Quebec) and am simply trying to create a map in PowerBI that highlights these regions.

It's no problem to do this if I have the individual states in a column, but unfortunately just have these regions.

I do have a list of States that are in each region, but haven't been able to figure out how to create a PowerBI map that takes any data for the "Southwest", and then uses that region to fill in TX, OK, and AR.

Is the way to go about this to actually get shapefiles, and somehow import into PowerBI and go from there? I've found https://geojson.io/ that can help, but it requires me to zoom in to make sure I create a shape around all parts of the state (Colorado isn't so bad, but say Michigan or Kentucky is a bit more involved to make sure I select the correct state boundaries).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options to try for this:

a) Region-State translation table: add a table to your model to translate the regions into states, one state per row. Add a relationship to connect it to your existing table with regions. Use the state column in the map - it should show the same value for each state in the Region, and light up the built-in US state shapes.  You could add the Region as a tooltip.

b) Custom Visuals - the IconMap and Mapbox Custom Visuals are two that I am aware of that have this capability. You feed them a shapefile of your custom regions, and you can show those regions with data-driven colors on a map.

Comment: I'm making good headway with the first suggestion, I was able to get the map separated into regions, but how can I overlay any of the data? (eg normally in maps, I can choose a Circle or Bar to represent the values)

Comment: From your description I imagined you wanted to color the state/region shapes using data, with the Filled map visual. If you prefer circles, the Map visual can do that - they call them Bubbles.